# С2060, С2061, С2065. Это все, что я могу сказать насчет о ошибке, ибо словами ее не описать :,>

Tags: c++, ооп, функции, классы, дружественная-функция

Функция объявлена как дружественная в классах(не помню, зачем я это сделал, но это факт), в нее передаются объекты классов. Все как надо. 
Однако компилятор из раза в раз ругается на функцию за приведенные выше ошибки. Банально не знаю, как их устранить, сколько бы не пытался.
Код:

```
set<string> sorting(set<string> a, binary& bin, octal& oct, hexademical& hex)
{
    set<string> answer; //Возвращаемый контейнер и объявление классов

    int temp, i = 0;    //Временные переменные
    string mirror_temp;
    int* arr = new int[a.size()]; //Числа для сортировки dec
    string* mirror_arr = new string[a.size()]; //Маркеры систем счисления
    string* second_arr = new string[a.size()]; //Отсортированные и переведенные в свои системы счисления числа 

    for (auto& one : a) //Разбитие контейнера на два массива (маркеры и числа), попутно переводя числа в dec
    {
        mirror_arr[i] = one[0];

        if (mirror_arr[i] == "b")
        {
            arr[i] = atoi(bin.rconvert(cutter(one)).c_str());
        }
        if (mirror_arr[i] == "o")
        {
            arr[i] = atoi(oct.rconvert(cutter(one)).c_str());
        }
        if (mirror_arr[i] == "h")
        {
            arr[i] = atoi(hex.rconvert(cutter(one)).c_str());
        }
        i++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a.size() - 1; i++) //Сортировка чисел, попутно отзеркаливая действия на маркерах
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.size() - i - 1; j++) 
        {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) 
            {
                temp = arr[j]; 
                mirror_temp = mirror_arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1]; 
                mirror_arr[j] = mirror_arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp; 
                mirror_arr[j + 1] = mirror_temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) //Возвращение числел в свои системы счисления
    {
        if (mirror_arr[i] == "b")
        {
            second_arr[i] = bin.convert(arr[i]);
        }
        if (mirror_arr[i] == "o")
        {
            second_arr[i] = oct.convert(arr[i]);
        }
        if (mirror_arr[i] == "h")
        {
            second_arr[i] = hex.convert(arr[i]);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) //Добавление результатов в контейнер
    {
        answer.insert(mirror_arr[i] + second_arr[i]);
    }

    return answer;
}
```

В мейне эта функция вызывается так:

```
c_set = sorting(c_set, bin, oct, hex);
```

Ниже я привел скриншот того, как это выглядит в самом компиляторе.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: неизвестные типы ни мне ни компилятору.

Comment: @AlexGlebe , это классы. Объекты классов. Я это упоминал в первом предложении.

Comment: Эти имена классов могут не распознаться если они в другом пространстве имён или в другом файле вообще. Скажите хотя-бы на какой по номеру строке эти классы определены.

Comment: @AlexGlebe , 306(bin), 366(oct), 417(hex)

Answer (score 2):

Вместо определения функции `sorting` с неизвестными типами нужно оставить только предварительные объявления типов и этой функции.

```
class binary;
class octal;
class hexademical;
set<string> sorting(set<string> , binary& , octal& , hexademical& );
```

И только после полных определений этих классов уже можно писать эту функцию.

```
set<string> sorting(set<string> a, binary& bin, octal& oct, hexademical& hex)
{ ...
```